# Error when using customizing list on bookclass

Tags: lists, book-class

I want the result exactly looks like this *without indent*

```
List :
1) One
2) Two
3) Three
```

Attempt:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
List :
\begin{enumerate}[left= 0pt][label=\arabic*)]
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But didn't work. And appears a lot of erros such as

```
Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{enumerate}[left= 0pt][label=\arabic*)]
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \item O
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \item T
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \item T
```

Please help me. Many thanks!

Comment: Where exactly have you learned that the enumerate package should support such a syntax? (hit it does not). Instead have a look at the enumitem package and read its manual, the options does **not** go into two sets of [], only one set, and the options are separated by commas

Comment: @daleif Actually there's a typo. Sorry. Please look my edit

Comment: There is also no option called left. Again please read the manual, every package has one.

Comment: @daleif ok thanks, i'l try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt, label=\arabic*)]
```

In case of multiline items, it you want theses lines to start at the text left margin, like the labels, simply use

```
\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, label=\arabic*)]
```